# access key and label in an Object and loop over another array and assign the key and label inside the looped array elements: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object called `roomDetails` and I need label from it. Once I've the  label I need to loop over `patientArray` and assign label as the value of roomLabel.

```
roomDetails = {

room01{label: "Room 1"},
room02{label: "Room 2"},
room03{label: "Room 3"},
room04{label: "Room 4"}
}
```

```
let patientArray = [

{ roomLabel: '', name: 'John'},
{ roomLabel: '', name: 'Shawn'},
{ roomLabel: '', name: 'Gereth'},
{ roomLabel: '', name: 'Elminster'}
]
```

so what patientArray should look like is

```
let patientaArray = [

{ roomLabel: 'Room 1', name: 'John'},
{ roomLabel: 'Room 2', name: 'Shawn'},
{ roomLabel: 'Room 3', name: 'Gereth'},
{ roomLabel: 'Room 4', name: 'Elminster'}
]
```

I've tried

```
   Object.keys(roomDetails).map((key, index) => {

            const roomLabel = roomDetails[key].label;
            console.log(roomLabel); // this outputs correctly as `Room 1`, `Room 2`.....

            patientArray.forEach((pi, index) => {


                pi.roomLabel = roomDetails[key].label; // output is always `Room 4`, the pi.roomLabel is being overwritten on each iteration. 

            });
        });
```

Please help me guide towards right solution and with my understanding. thank you.

Comment: Your object does not have a correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

`roomDetails` is not an object in your code.

The following snippet is not a really good one, as it's not "defended" against different lengths of the **roomDetails** object and **patientArray**. I think you'd have to think of a more careful algorithm to take care of all the different possible cases.

And also: you shouldn't mutate **patientArray** - it's not a good idea to modify the input data. It's much better to create a copy of it (**map()** returns a new array with the modified values; **patientArray** is left as it was at the beginning.

```js
const roomDetails = {
  room01: {
    label: "Room 1"
  },
  room02: {
    label: "Room 2"
  },
  room03: {
    label: "Room 3"
  },
  room04: {
    label: "Room 4"
  }
}

const patientArray = [{
    roomLabel: '',
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    roomLabel: '',
    name: 'Shawn'
  },
  {
    roomLabel: '',
    name: 'Gereth'
  },
  {
    roomLabel: '',
    name: 'Elminster'
  }
]

const finalArray = Object.values(roomDetails).map((e, i) => {
  return {
    roomLabel: e.label,
    name: patientArray[i].name
  }
})

console.log(finalArray)
```